# Christianity.SE Blogs

Tags: discussion

I know we used to have a blog entries for Christianity SE.  I would like to polish my answer here: [How was Lucifer created?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-was-lucifer-created/34138#34138)

and make it a blog entry for future questions regarding Lucifer.  I would like it (if it's possible) to make it more of a wiki type entry were others can add to it.

Comment: Neat idea. I'm cool with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your meta post doesn't include very much detail about what you have in mind, but at first glance it doesn't sound like what you have in mind for that post fits the motif of the blog.

1. For technical reasons, blog entries are not wikis. They are not community collaborations they are the ramblings of specific individuals. If you want a wiki type entry, the main QnA site is the place to have it.

   The best home for canonical answers about any given topic is the QnA site. The blog is only intended as a supplementary outlet for community opinions in a format that don't fit the main site.
2. The C.SE blog is known as Eschewmenical because the concept behind it (that worked well and is likely to be continued if revived) is to delve into and highlight the *different* approaches to theology taken by different traditions. This is really the only way we found to avoid it being a battle ground for ongoing disparity between belief systems. Any attempt to make it ecumenical would undoubtedly alienate it from many/most users of this site.

   Reviewing the current state of your past it is not clear to me what it represents. It miss-characterizes the issue as understood from several different major perspectives, but as it makes no particular claim to represent any specific branch of Christianity it seems like it has every likelihood of being wrong and slim chances at being right according to any random sampling. That's exactly the opposite of the current blog concept.

The latter issue could change if somebody suggested and got community backing for a different concept, but the first item isn't likely to change. Given that detail and the general motif, I'm not sure what purpose you see in making that a blog post.

That being said if somebody wants to organize a series for the blog with posts from a couple (clearly identified) positions on Satan, I'd say go for it.